# How to make scala type parameter inference smarter?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, generic-type-argument

I have a function that takes a type parameter `T` that has to be a subtype of `this.type`:

```
def injectFrom[T <: this.type](same: T): Unit = ...
```

however every time I use it, the compiler gave me a

> type T cannot be inferred" error

and every time it can be fixed by specifying `T` explicitly as `(instance_variable).type`. How can I avoid doing this in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.type` is a type of an individual object or class instance, not of the class.

In the following code `a1` and `a2` will have different `this.type`:

```
class A
val a1 = new A()
val a2 = new A()
```

So type parameter `[T <: this.type]` doesn't really make sense as you can't `extend` an `object` or an instance.

If you want to have a design, so that functions in subclasses can accept only instances of that subclass (and consequently instances of subclasses only of that subclass) you would have to make the type explicit by using type parameter or type variable:

```
trait A {
    type Self
    def injectFrom(same: Self): Unit = ???
}
class B extends A {
    type Self = B
}
class C extends A {
    type Self = C
}
```

or something that Scala does for example in [`Ordered`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/math/Ordered.scala) implementation:

```
trait A[Self] {
    def injectFrom(same: Self): Unit = ???
}
class B extends A[B]
class C extends A[C]
```

In both cases `new B().injectFrom(new B())` will compile but `new B().injectFrom(new C())` won't.

The modification of the second example that allows you to have `this injectFrom this` inside `A`:

```
trait A[Self] {
    def injectFrom(same: A[Self]): Unit = ???
    def test() {
        this injectFrom this
    }
}
```

Comment: The second solution looks very simple. But when I define another function in A[Self] that invokes this.inject(this) (just for testing), the compiler says: type mismatch: expected: Self, actual: A[Self]

Comment: Interesting,  I wonder if the recursive pattern Self >: A[Self] can be useful, this seems to be very gnarly

Comment: @tribbloid I've updated with a simple fix in the second example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My earlier attempt doesn't work: illegal cyclic reference involving type Self
[ERROR] trait A[Self >: A[Self]]

Comment: Your update gave me the following compiler error: Self does not take type parameters

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That was a misprint. Look now

Comment: OK I see your point. In general it definitely works, but it sounds to be a very verbose hack: every override of injectFrom in subclass has to do a type cast to use subclass' specific method & field. May be the recursive pattern will work again

Comment: Sorry looks like the recursive pattern was for a different purpose, I'll just stick with your solution and do the verbose typecast

Comment: @tribbloid What do you mean by typecast? I think override should look like this: `class B extends A[B] {override def injectFrom(same: B): Unit = {// can use B methods of same here}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69629/discussion-between-tribbloid-and-kolmar).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler resolutely refuses to infer a singleton type.

```
scala> class C { def f[A <: this.type](a: A) = ??? }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C
c: C = C@71f2a7d5

scala> c f c
<console>:10: error: inferred type arguments [C] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A <: c.type]
              c f c
                ^
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C
 required: A
              c f c
                  ^
```

The classic reference:

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/modular-programming-using-objects.html#i-108236764-1

> Usually such types are too specific to be useful, which is why the
>   compiler is reluctant to insert them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?  I don't know if this is the best way, but...

```
trait Foo {
  class Tag[U <: AnyRef](x: U) {
    type UT = U
  }
  val tag = new Tag(this)
  def injectFrom[T <: tag.UT](same: T): Unit = {
    println("Injected")
    ()
  }
}

class NotBar
{
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
  injectFrom(this)
  val notThis = new NotBar
  injectFrom(notThis)
}
```

Results in:

```
x.scala:20: error: inferred type arguments [NotBar] do not conform to method injectFrom's type parameter bounds [T <: Bar.this.tag.UT]
  injectFrom(notThis)
  ^
x.scala:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : NotBar
 required: T
  injectFrom(notThis)
             ^
two errors found
```

EDIT: This might not be what you are looking for, since this will allow injection of any subtypes of this class, not injection from the specific subtype of the instance?