# In Scala, How to define a class method that only takes subclass-type argument?

Tags: scala, generic-type-argument

I've tried

```
def function[T <: this.type](parameter: T)
```

but it doesn't work.

This should just be a simple problem and its too heavyweight to define a CanBuildFrom and import it everytime before using the function

Comment: "it doesn't work" how? What goes wrong? (also, couldn't that be written more simply as `def function(parameter: this.type)`?)

Comment: when you use A.function(B) when both A & B are of the same type, the compiler complaints: type mismatch: expected A$1.type actual: B.

Comment: The exact reason, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157785/how-to-make-scala-type-parameter-inference-smarter, is that this.type is the type of the object, which cannot be subclassed

Comment: `this.type` is the singleton type of this instance. What did you want? If this is in a class `Foo` and you want `parameter` to be a `Foo`, can't you just take `parameter: Foo`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the class is abstract, with most of its subclasses modifying it to be coherent with their respective implementations

Answer (score 1):

The standard collections encode it with a type param.

```
scala> abstract class X[Repr <: X[Repr]] { def f(r: Repr) }
defined class X

scala> class Y extends X[Y] { def f(y: Y) = ??? }
defined class Y

scala> val y = new Y
y: Y = Y@6ae40994

scala> y f y
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  at Y.f(<console>:8)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: in this case f cannot be used in other functions of X, it gives you a type mismatch error

Comment: a counter example and its hack-ish solution is presented at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157785/how-to-make-scala-type-parameter-inference-smarter